# Angular bootstrap datepicker - how to set date explicitly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

The [Angularjs Bootstrap datepicker](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) is amazing. But I face a problem when I try to select the date by javascript. For example, If read this data from a particular object, 4/5/1990, how can I make the datepicker selected date as that date: 4/5/1990 ?

Hint: I need this when I make data available for user for edit.

Take a look at my current code:

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="Birthdate" id="Birthdate" name="Birthdate" required autocomplete="on" datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy" is-open="opened" max-date="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"
                               ng-required="true" close-text="Close" placeholder="Enter Birthdate"  />
```

js

```
$scope.Birthdate = $scope.users[id].Birthdate;
```

But the selected date appears in two cases:

First case: In case the date is 4/5/1986, it swap day and month of the date format. i.e: 4/5/1990  ---becomes---> 5/4/1990

Second case: no date is selected in case of this date: 28/5/1986

Please help me to select the date in the datepicker as I read it from the object, if it is 4/51990, the datepicker selected date should be exactly that date  with no mess. And in case I have this date 28/5/1986, the datepicker should stick/be selecting that date.

Comment: So what format are you getting the data to bind as if you're editing it? YYYY-MM-DD? And which are you trying to display? MM/DD/YYYY or DD/MM/YYYY?

Comment: @JeremyJackson What I am trying to display is same as what I read from the object. DD/MM/YYYY

Comment: So the object date is stored as DD/MM/YYYY? What happens if you format it as YYYY-MM-DD?

Comment: @JeremyJackson Why? Maybe I did not understand what you aim to?

Comment: I thought maybe that would do it, but after a bit of research that isn't the case. Can you post your dateOptions variable?

Comment: Yeah either me I tried it but no benefit. thanks anyway. I did not get you on  posting my dateOptions variable? Please be informed that everything related is already posted either on HTML or js above.

Answer (score 1):

see this plnkr
http://plnkr.co/edit/mDHliPweKoUNOAmVv5oo?p=preview

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<pre>Raw date is: <em>{{dt}}</em></pre>
```

your date retrieved from the server should have the same format as Raw date to be accepted by date picker you cannot pass already formated dates as Model this is the problem here

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1**: If read this data from a particular object, 4/5/1990, how can I make the datepicker selected date as that date: 4/5/1990 
First case: In case the date is 4/5/1986, it swap day and month of the date format. i.e: 4/5/1990 ---becomes---> 5/4/1990
**Override today function**:

```
$scope.today = function() {
$scope.dt = "4/5/1990"; };  $scope.today();
```

**Question 2**: no date is selected in case of this date: 28/5/1986 
**Answer**: Use moment.js. This because using string to set date is always erroneous. It always recommended to use some standard lib.

```
$scope.today = function() {
$scope.dt = moment("28/5/1986", "DD-MM-YYYY").format();};  $scope.today();
```

Moment JS is a wonderful library to use when you want to format dates.

**Example**: http://plnkr.co/edit/NWQutvl8vXY9YP2LoIZ8

Answer (score 0):

The returned date by the datepicker is i.e 2015-06-03T15:25:51.211Z. But I truncate it to be: 2015-06-03 and save it in databse.

The problems comes now, when I bind 2015-06-03 to datepicker, it does not accept it. It accepts this only: 2015-06-03T15:25:51.211Z

That was the problem that I discovered, I solved it by not truncating the date and store it as 2015-06-03T15:25:51.211Z. The datepicker became able to bind it for edit by user.

Answer (score 0):

@AbuTaha: This problem can also be solved by using moment js.

```
$scope.today = function() {
$scope.dt = moment("2015-06-03T15:25:51.211Z", "YYYY-MM-DD").format();  };  $scope.today();
```

Comment: seems like overkill, considering moment.js is a 3k liine library